# Detect sqlplus error in dos batch script?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, batch-file

We have the following batch script:

```
(
echo @release.sql
echo exit
) | sqlplus x/y@orcl

if %errorlevel% gtr 1 goto dberror
```

Issue is - the statement `if %errorlevel% gtr 1` never appears to be true when there is a sql error.

If we put garbage commands in the release.sql file, sqlplus does complain:

```
SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command "blah" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

But `%errorlevel%` still equals 0.  How can we determine that there was a sql error?

---

**Update**: This code DOES appear to work for some sql errors.  It will work if I do `drop table blah` but it won't work with just the command `blah`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at:

WHENEVER SQLERROR

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm

WHENEVER OSERROR

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve051.htm