# Can I make SQL*Plus exit with an error on function compilation failure?

Tags: oracle, error-handling, sqlplus, compiler-warnings

I've been working on an Oracle function that will be deployed in an automated fashion via SQL*Plus. Sometimes I make a mistake, and Oracle says:

> Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

I can then use `SHOW ERR` to see the error, but I'm wondering if there is some configuration I can set such that, on such a compilation error:

- The function will not be created
- The underlying error will be emitted
- SQL*PLus will exit with a non-0 exit value

Something like [`WHENEVER SQLERROR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937654/79202) would be awesome.

Comment: The free Oracle SQL Developer provides a much better environment to develop PL/SQL code in than the ancient SQL*Plus. Same for running scripts against a database.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot use it from batch files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, but you can.

The initial `CREATE FUNCTION` or `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement will create the function or procedure.  You'd have to detect in your script that there were errors and explicitly drop the function and/or procedure if there were errors.  But you'd have to capture the errors before dropping the object.  That will require some code in your script after the `CREATE` statement.

```
whenever sqlerror exit failure;

create or replace procedure compile_error
as
begin
  select count(*)
    into no_such_variable
    from emp;
end;
/

show error;

declare
  l_num_errors integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_num_errors
    from user_errors
   where name = 'COMPILE_ERROR';

 if( l_num_errors > 0 )
 then
   execute immediate 'DROP PROCEDURE compile_error';
   raise_application_error( -20001, 'Errors in COMPILE_ERROR' );
 end if;
end;
/
```

When executed, this script will produce the following output which includes the errors and will drop the procedure.

```
SQL> @c:\temp\compile_errors.sql

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Errors for PROCEDURE COMPILE_ERROR:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/10     PLS-00201: identifier 'NO_SUCH_VARIABLE' must be declared
6/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Errors in COMPILE_ERROR
ORA-06512: at line 12


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Comment: Hrm. `user_errors` is empty for me. Ah, but it's in `all_errors` so I will just use that.

Comment: @theory - If you use `all_errors`, make sure that you add a predicate on the `OWNER` as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. I am also selecting `text` to include in the output of `raise_application_error()`, rather than calling `SHOW ERRORS`. This is to suppress the output of "No errors." when there are no errors. Would be nice if I could just capture the output of `SHOW ERRORS`, instead…